# iOS: Download video from url and save in gallery......?

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox

I can't figure out how to download video from url and save it to the gallery.

```
BOOL compatible = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum([videoURL path]);
        // save
        NSLog(@"BOOL compatible....%hhd",compatible);

        if (compatible){
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([videoURL path], nil, nil, nil);
            NSLog(@"SAVED!!!! %@",[videoURL path]);
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"INCOMPATIBLE...");
        }
```

when download video showing error:https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/4185382/download cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x7f9c13ccb130 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9c13cc3aa0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory",

Comment: Yor video URL is incorrect.

Comment: I can not understand which video URL is incorrect.

Comment: @KlimczakM _how_ is the video URL incorrect - just telling someone that they are wrong doesn't help them solve their problem!

Comment: The URL from the question is correct of course. What I meant is that the URL passed in the code may be incorrect. More would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.I hope it will work properly.:

```
    -(void)DownloadVideo
{
//download the file in a seperate thread.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.mp4";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
    {
    NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"thefile.mp4"];

    //saving is done on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"File Saved !");
    });
    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum) I think that `UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum` only works on local files, not remote ones. The same will be true for `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

You will need to download the file to your device first, before you can use `UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum`. I would recommend using something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to do that.